# Specific Ordering of a List of Objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ and I want to order a list using one of the columns in my DB table. The issue is that I want to order a list of people by their branch which I am able to do but I want to place the branch in a certain order.

Right now I am using this:

```
phoneList.OrderBy(e => e.Branch).ThenBy(e => e.FullName)
```

Say that i have these branches avaialble: 82pk,corp,prfe,hrbd.

My current code will sort the people in this branch order:  82pk,corp,hrbd,prfe

I want to sort the people in this branch order: corp,82pk,prfe,hrbd

How can I use LINQ to order my list manually given my specific order?

This is what i am trying to accomplish:

```
phoneList.OrderBy(e => e.Branch == corp).ThenBy(e => e.Branch == 82pk).ThenBy(e => e.Branch == prfe).ThenBy(e => e.Branch == hrbd)
```

Comment: The code that you have already does exactly what you're asking it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with an array of your required order

```
var branchOrder = new[]{"corp","82pk","prfe","hrbd"};
```

Then order by the index position in this list:

```
phoneList.OrderBy(e => branchOrder.IndexOf(e.Branch)).ThenBy(e => e.FullName);
```

This has the added benefit that it works as expected even with EF queries.

---

This will get slower as the number of items grows, as described in comments there is a simple enhancement to store the "branch" and required order in a dictionary.

```
var branchOrder = new Dictionary<string,int>(){
  {"corp",1},
  {"82pk",2},
  ... etc
}
phoneList.OrderBy(
           e => branchOrder.ContainsKey(e.Branch)
              ? branchOrder[e.Branch] 
              : 0) // give a default to protect against invalid key
        .ThenBy(e => e.FullName);
```

Comment: That's going to take an exceedingly long time if the number of branches is large. You'd probably want to store the order in a `Dictionary<string,int>` instead. Or, store it in the database and let the SQL do the ordering.

Comment: Very clever alternative to doing a custom comparer!

Comment: @JimMischel - yep, thats a great enhancement but this is the simplest to understand first step.

Comment: I really like the dictionary idea. I think I will add this to my solution. Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Let your Branch-class implement ICompareble with the logic you described. Then Linq's OrderBy will sort as you want.

Comment: Doesnt help when this is EF and what you need is it to produce the right database query

Comment: @Jamiec You think your answer can be translated into SQL?